# Determining if Argument is Valid via Short-Cut Method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I understand there are two ways to determine validity of an argument. The first way is to construct a truth table and if the statement consisting of the premises combined together implying the conclusion is a tautology, then it is valid.

The other method is to use the fact that it no valid arguments have all premises to be true and the conclusion to be false. So we could assume that the conclusion is false, and work are way through the premises, determining their truth. This is the "short cut" method.

With regards to this question, how could you use the short cut method?

P

Q -> (R->S)

U -> R

P V Q

---

~S -> ~U

So we would assume ~S -> ~U is false. Does that mean that S -> U would be true? Where would we take it from here.

Comment: In the 1st paragraph, "and if the premises combined together create a tautology, then it is valid" isn't quite right. It has to be something more long-winded: "and if the formula $p\to q$ is a tautology, where $p$ is the conjunction of the premises and $q$ is the conclusion, then it is valid".

Comment: The negation of $\neg S \to \neg U$ is not what you have. The negation of $p\to q$ is $\neg(p\to q)\equiv (p\land \neg q)$.

Comment: Finally, I don't understand your explanation of the "shortcut method": "So we could assume that the conclusion is **true**, and work are way through the premises, determining their truth." If you *assume* the conclusion to be true, then anything implies it, even false premises. Perhaps you mean, assume the conclusion to be *false*, then derive a contradiction?

Comment: see edits..I have found the answer. it is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You last comment is right: the argument is invalid.

An argument is *valid* if and only if there is no possible situation in which the premisses would be true and the conclusion false.

From this, it follows that

> an argument with true premisses and a false conclusion can't be *valid*.

What you call "the short cut method" is a semantical proof by contradiction, i.e. assuming the falsity of the conclusion and trying to derive a contradiction.

---

Thus, we have to assume that $\lnot S \to \lnot U$ is *false* (which does not means that $S \to U$ is true...), i.e.:

> $\lnot S$ *true* and $\lnot U$ *false*, i.e. $S$ *false* and $U$ *true*.

The *premises* must be all *true*; thus $P$ (first premise) is *true* and this is enough to satisfy also the fourth one: $P \lor Q$.

Assuming $U$ *true* implies that, with the third premise: $U \to R$, that also $R$ must be *true*.

Consider now the second premise: $Q \to (R \to S)$.

Up to now we have:

> $S$ *false*, $U$ *true*, $P$ *true* and $R$ *true*.

Thus: $R \to S$ is *false* and this implies $Q$ *false*.

This is "compatible" with the satisfaction of $P \lor Q$, and thus we have found no contradiction, i.e. the argument is *invalid*.

Answer (score 1):

You have the premises $P, Q \to (R \to S), U\to R, P\vee Q$ and wish to quickly see if that entails $\lnot S\to\lnot U$.

An argument is defined as *invalid* when there exists an interpretation (valuation of the literals) which satisfies all the premises but not the conclusion.   Two of the premises are conditional statements; which are satisfied when their consequent is valued as true *or* their antecedent is valued as false.

Well $\lnot S\to\lnot U$ is **unsatisfied** when $S$ *and* $\lnot U$ hold (ie: when valuing $S$ as true *and* $U$ as false).   Now, valuing $S$ as true satisfies the second premise, valuing $U$ as false satisfies the third premise, and to satisfy the other two premises we just need to also value $P$ as true.

So there *is* an interpretation which will satisfy the four premises but not the conclusion.

The argument is therefore invalid, by definition.   These premises do *not* entail $\lnot S\to\lnot U$.