# Discrete Math: Determining if Argument is Valid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I understand there are two ways to determine validity of an argument. The first way is to construct a truth table and if the statement consisting of the premises combined together implying the conclusion is a tautology, then it is valid.

The other method is to use the fact that it no valid arguments have all premises to be true and the conclusion to be false. So we could assume that the conclusion is false, and work are way through the premises, determining their truth. This is the "short cut" method.

With regards to this question, how could you use the short cut method?

$P \lor Q$

$(P \to \sim R) \land [Q\to (S \,\lor \sim S)]$

$(S \to \sim R) \land [\sim S \to (T \lor U)]$

$(T \to \sim R) \land (U \to  \sim W)$

---

$\sim R \,\lor \sim W$

So we would assume $\sim R \,\lor \sim W$ is false. Where would we take it from here.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: See the answer to your previous [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642497/determining-if-argument-is-valid-via-short-cut-method).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the conclusion is false, then $\;R\land W\;\implies\; $ both atoms have value true.

For the last line to be true, both parts have to be true. Since $\;\neg R\,,\,\,\neg W\;$ are false, it must be that also $\;T\,,\,\,U\;$ are false.

Going to the next up line, it also must be $\;S\;$ is false but also $\;\neg S\;$ is false, which means $\;S\;$ is true, and we've reached a contradiction.

Comment: I don't quite get how you can assume $R \land W$ to be true...

Comment: If $\sim R \,\lor \sim W$ is false, then doesn't that mean either part can be false? Thus, either $R, could be true or  $W could be true?

Comment: I use de Morgan Rule: $$\neg\left(\neg R\lor \neg W\right)=\neg\neg R\land\neg\neg W=R\land W$$

Answer (score 0):

Begin by assuming that $R\wedge W$.  Apply that to statement 4,

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{l|l:l}
1. & P\vee Q & \textsf{Premise}
\\ 2. & (P \to \neg R) \wedge [Q\to (S \vee \neg S)] & \textsf{Premise}
\\ 3. & (S \to \neg R) \land [\neg S \to (T \lor U)] & \textsf{Premise}
\\ 4. & (T \to \neg R) \land (U \to  \neg W) & \textsf{Premise}
\\ \hdashline \quad 5. & \neg (\neg R \lor \neg  W) & \textsf{Assume}
\\ \quad 6. & R\wedge W & 5, \textsf{deMorgan's Law}
\\ \quad 7. & R & 6, \textsf{Conjunction Elimination}
\\ \quad 8. & W & 6, \textsf{Conjunction Elimination}
\\ \quad 9. & T\to\neg R & 4, \textsf{Conjunction Elimination}
\\ \quad 10. & U\to \neg W & 4, \textsf{Conjunction Elimination} 
\\ \quad 11. & \neg T & 7, 9, \textsf{Modus Tollens}
\\ \quad 12. & \neg U & 7, 10, \textsf{Modus Tollens}
\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}}$$

And so forth, until you obtain a contradiction.